# Mysql Select items by UPDATE status. [Syntax Error]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to work a mysql query. I'm not sure, maybe there is not available syntax like that. Or maybe there is, but I can't use right.

Anyway, my query is that:

```
SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `username`='testuser' AND 1 IN ( UPDATE `user` SET `lastcheck` = NOW() WHERE `username`='testuser' );
```

There are two "where" condicitions. First for right user, secound is  update check about lastcheck.

I'm testing it by PhpMyAdmin sql page. System is giving this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `user` SET `lastcheck` = NOW() WHERE `username`='testuser' ) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Comment: You can't have an update statement as a subquery. It needs to be a select statement.

Comment: What do you expect `1 IN (UPDATE ...)` to do?  `UPDATE` doesn't return any rows/values.

Comment: You'd need to do this as 2 queries.  First run the `UPDATE`, then `SELECT` the rows you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax available in MySQL to perform an `UPDATE` statement within a `SELECT` statement.

In the general case, a MySQL stored function is one way to workaround this (i.e. execute an UPDATE statement from within the stored function), but this won't work in your specific case, since you'd be attempting to modify a table that's already in use. (And that's a restriction on MySQL stored functions.)

To do what it appears you are attempting to do, just run two separate statements:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `lastcheck` = NOW() WHERE `username`='testuser';
SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `username`='testuser;
```

Answer (score -1):

I see one problem with your query. You don't need quotes around field names or table names. Just the char string you expect to be contained in the field:

```
SELECT Email from user where Username = 'testuser'
```

Comment: He doesn't have *quotes* around field/table names.  He has backticks, which is correct to use here.

Comment: The backticks around the identifiers is not a problem in the query. The problem is the attempt to execute an `UPDATE` statement within the context of a `SELECT` statement. That's the problem in the query.